# Jquery load() with # troubleshooting

Tags: jquery

I have a page with three inputs, color1, color2 and color3.
Once the user enters either an hex value or a colorname I need to load script.php inside #mydiv :

```
$("#color1").change(function() {
    $("#mydiv").load("script.php?color1=" + this.value + "&color2=" + color2.value + "&color3=" + color3.value + "");
});
```

The problem I'm facing is that # causes Jquery to stop at script.php?color1= and I was wondering if there is any chance to bypass this problem besides substring(1) (for I want the user to keep seeing the # in the input)

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values need to be properly encoded using `encodeURIComponent()`. Otherwise chars like `#` or `&` will break things. So instead of `this.value` you'd use `encodeURIComponent(this.value)`.

However, since you are using jQuery you have a much nicer way: The `data` argument accepts an object in which case jQuery takes care of the escaping. However, it switches to POST in that case - but if that's not a problem for you it's the cleanest way:

```
$("#color1").change(function() {
    $("#mydiv").load("script.php", {
        color1: this.value,
        ...
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help onto this matter. Indeed encodeURIComponent(this.value) works like a charm and I'll look into the data arguments. Thank you big time.